# uploading yii2 basic on shared hosting but not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

I am installing Yii2 on a shared hosting environment,Apache, (Godaddy),
here is what I did as per the docs:

1. Renamed web folder to www
2. copied all the folders, now the directory structure looks like this:

   public_html\

   ```
    assets
    commands
    config
    controllers
    model
    modules
    views
    www\index.php 
    .htaccess (this is both in public_html and www)
   ```

but when I access my domain, I get the following error:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a
>   404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Here are the contents of my .htaccess which I have copied in both public_html and www.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

is the htaccess creating problem?  Is  index.php  not being run from the right folder? What else should I look for? any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**

The actual problem with the above error was that It was a Permissions issue.
Set the permissions from 644 to 755, and now the system is accessible.

**BUT**
the to access index.php I still need to navigate to it manually by typing in the url : www.example.com/www/index.php

**UPDATE**

As I don't have prettyurl's enabled, just to make it work, I deleted all the contents of the .htaccess, then I copied the contents of `basic` folder in the home folder (for future visitors it should be like `home/your_user _name`

**CAVEAT EMPTOR**

I know almost nothing about .htaccess. Also my this project is just for learning, this solution may not be useful in production settings.

Question is still open for expert advice on best practices in such scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your domain pointer to www instead of htdocs, its probably somewhere under `domain -> root folder`. Your .htaccess looks fine.